# Naming a service changes dependency injection behavior in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a factory service class which needs access to Symfony´s (v6.0.2) service_container and is specified in the services.yaml as follows:

```
App\Service\SomeService:
    public: true
    arguments: ['%some_arguments%']
    calls:
        - [ setContainer, [ '@service_container' ] ]
```

It works fine and I can access the service container and all the other injected arguments from within my service as desired.

However, if I change the service definition into a named service like this - without changing anything else:

```
app.some_service:
    class: App\Service\SomeService
    public: true
    arguments: ['%some_arguments%']
    calls:
        - [ setContainer, [ '@service_container' ] ]
```

I still have access to the injected arguments ("%some_arguments%"), but the service container suddenly becomes null.

I would expect the behavior of the dependency injection to be the same - regardless of whether I use a named service or not.

Does the DI behavior change as soon as I give my service a name or do I need to take another approach if I want to give my service a name?

Comment: Are you using $container->get('app.some_service') to get your service or something different?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Cerad. 

As this is managed by the built-in Dependency Injection mechanism provided by Symfony, I do not use $container->get() to retrieve the service, but rely on Symfony to insert the "@service_container" into my service - this is done with the "calls" - directive, which accepts a setter (setContainer) and the service to be automatically injected ("@service_container" in my case)..

Comment: So you manually wired up another service and explicitly used '@app.some_service' as an argument?  You are not just relying on autowire to inject a parameter typehinted as App\Service\SomeService?  Unless you explicitly excluded App\Service\SomeService.php or you are not using autowire at all then I suspect you may actually have two services defined.  One with an id of app.some_service and one with App\Service\SomeService.  Maybe you could update your question to clarify how your service is actually injected.